# Beginner Redis Command

Tags: redis, ttl

I'm going through the [tutorial](http://try.redis.io/) on redis and came across a command that didn't make sense. From my code below, I'm getting a `-2` time-to-live return value for a key that definitely does still exist. Shouldn't my code have returned a `-1` for never expiring?

The tutorial says:

> Redis can be told that a key should only exist for a certain length of time. This is accomplished with the EXPIRE and TTL commands.
>
> SET resource:lock "Redis Demo"
>      EXPIRE resource:lock 120
>
> This causes the key resource:lock to be deleted in 120 seconds. You can test how long a key will exist with the TTL command. It returns the number of seconds until it will be deleted.
>
> TTL resource:lock => 113
>      // after 113s
>      TTL resource:lock => -2
>
> The -2 for the TTL of the key means that the key does not exist (anymore). A -1 for the TTL of the key means that it will never expire. Note that if you SET a key, its TTL will be reset.
>
> SET resource:lock "Redis Demo 1"
>      EXPIRE resource:lock 120
>      TTL resource:lock => 119
>      SET resource:lock "Redis Demo 2"
>      TTL resource:lock => -1

This is the code that I typed into the interactive terminal. My assumption is that the 3rd line should've given me back -1, for never expiring. I never set an expiration time so I don't know why I'm getting back -2.

```
> SET loggedIn "True"  
OK 
> TTL logggedIn   
(integer) -2  
> GET loggedIn  
"True"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spelling error: you set a key named `loggedIn`, while trying to get the TTL of `logggedIn`